# Magento 2.4 Production mode issue

Tags: magento2.3, production-mode, magento2.4, csp

After upgrade Magento `2.3` to `2.4` and it gives me below error.

```
main.CRITICAL: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/html/magento24/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml:15
```

Does anyone face this type of error? If I have solved this its gives me an error on another file.

It just because of below types of script

```
<?php $scriptString = <<<script

require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){

    // <![CDATA[
    (function($) {
        var test = 'test';
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(test, test);
            localStorage.removeItem(test);
        } catch(e) {
            $(".notice.global.site.local_storage").show();
        }
    })(jQuery);
    // ]]>

});
script;
?>
```

If anyone has any solution for this type of error then please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

you may replace your code

```
<?php $scriptString = <<<script

require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){

    // <![CDATA[
    (function($) {
        var test = 'test';
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(test, test);
            localStorage.removeItem(test);
        } catch(e) {
            $(".notice.global.site.local_storage").show();
        }
    })(jQuery);
    // ]]>

});
script;
?>
```

by the following

```
<?php $scriptString = <<<script

require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){

    // <![CDATA[
    (function($) {
        var test = 'test';
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(test, test);
            localStorage.removeItem(test);
        } catch(e) {
            $(".notice.global.site.local_storage").show();
        }
    })(jQuery);
    // ]]>

});
script;
```

basically closing php tags are not needed/wanted in Magento and can lead to complex debugs.

Comment: I already know about that but my friend change in the vendor file is not a solution. because this issue is not in a single file if solve this it give me a same error on another files.

Comment: fair enough, you might update your question with the second error.. maybe you think they are the same but in fact they may not be. At the moment, the error you show is a syntax error mentioning end of file, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the above commands but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?
(this for developer mode)

`rm -Rf vendor/*`

`rm -Rf generated/*`

`composer install`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Cheers

Comment: I also tried to install fresh Magento 2.4 and start production mode but face same issue.

Comment: I have noticed everything is working if I set HTML minify=No. But it's not a solution. If you have any other solution then please let me know.